# Sed script branching issue

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am having the darnedest time trying to figure out how to write `sed` scripts; specifically with labels and branching.

For example,  I want to remove all the newline (`\n`) in a text file.  If I do it on a command line

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;/s/\n/ /g' testfile.txt
```

does exactly what I expect it to do; all the newlines are removed.

The problem comes in if I put the commands into a script file (scrub.sed) as such:

```
:a
N
$!b a
s|\n| |g
```

and execute it with

```
sed -f scrub.sed testfile.txt
```

I get the following errors:

```
sed: 3: scrub.sed: whitespace after branch
sed: 5: scrub.sed: undefined label 'a '
```

I am trying to follow the syntax described [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch06_04.htm)

```
:top
command1
command2
/pattern/b top
command3
```

I'm editing the file using nano in FreeBSD and I can't find any "whitespace" after the branch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your script works fine for me on GNU `sed`, even in forced POSIX mode. And even when I add additional spaces after the label. I suggest you print your script in hex (with `hd` or `od`) and check there are no whitespaces after that label, including `\r`, etc. Additionally, you can try adding semicolons, like `:a;` and `$!b a;`.

Comment: @randomir - thanks for the suggestion.  I initially tried adding semicolons after and it had no effect.  `hd` showd some white space, no `\r` but I had no idea where it was coming from. I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was `nano`, the editor I was using to create the file.**

When I recreated the file in `vi` the problem went away; the script ran with no problems.

In `nano`, I enabled the display of whitespaces (<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) and got the following:

```
:a
N.
$!ba.
s|\n|.|g
```

(Periods being where the whitespaces are)

Once I removed the whitespaces, it worked.  I attempted to create another file being careful not to add any space between the lines but for some reason, `nano` added them in.  I don't know why `nano` exhibits this behavior, but at least there an an answer to move forward.